# Use str_replace to obfuscate the name with php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

How can I `echo $name` so that only the first 5 characters are shown as alphabets and the rest are shown as *-marks. 
For example `echo $name` prints `'Test ***'` not `'Test Guy'`?

Comment: I think yuou should use: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer `str_pad()` over regex functions in this case:

```
$pattern = 'Test Guy';
echo str_pad(substr($pattern,0,4), strlen($pattern), '*');
```

Easier, since padding *is* what you want to do, and offering better performance, since no slow regexes have to be compiled and applied...

Comment: Yes! KISS (Keep It Simple and Stupid). Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In your case (looks like you want to replace all characters except 'space' with '*') you can use this.

```
$str = "Test Guy";
echo substr($str, 0, 4) . preg_replace('/[^\s]/', '*', substr($str, 4));
```

output:
**Test *****

It's a little bit universal and you can use it with another strings like:

```
$str = "This is random string";
echo substr($str, 0, 4) . preg_replace('/[^\s]/', '*', substr($str, 4));
```

output:
**This ** ****** ********

I guess next that you have to do it wrap this code to the function like so:

```
function get_strange_string($str, $clear = 4) {
    return substr($str, 0, $clear) 
           . preg_replace('/[^\s]/', '*', substr($str, $clear));
}
```